# htaccess redirect from a folder to another one, but not from its subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

can anyone tell me what's the best way to redirect a specific folder to another one?

for example:

```
folderName1 -> subFolderName1
            -> subFolderName2 
            -> subFolderName3
folderName2
```

and when i get "folderName1" (but **not** the specific "subFolderName1/2/3") i'm redirect automatically into "folderName2".

thanks a lot!

Comment: So your logic is folderName1 gets redirected to folderName2 and subFolderName doesn't get redirected anywhere. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

If my comment above is true then:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^folderName1/ /folderName2/ [R,NC]
```

Comment: thanks for answering :)
im just trying to redirect a folder to another one, my site is based on wordpress:

RewriteBase /www/website.com/http/
RewriteRule ^category/collection/ category/collection/date [R,NC]

it doesn't work, can you tell me where im wrong?

Comment: if date is a folder, it will need a trailing slash:

RewriteRule ^category/collection/ category/collection/date/ [R,NC]

Comment: thanks you matt. maybe i'm making some mistakes in other parts of my htaccess. http://pastebin.com/yUEcTuGY do you see something that could broke my code?

Comment: it doesn't work, even if i write the complete path RewriteRule ^http://workspace/website.com/http/category/collection/ http://workspace/website.com/http/category/collection/date/ [R,NC]   very frustrating :D

Comment: Hi Luca, sorry about the delay. Could you expand on your question a little for me? Try and explain the exact situation as what we are trying to do is overwrite wordpress' core rules for clean URLs. There may be another way around your situation.